# Continues Runtime Exception : android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw on samsung devices

Tags: android, android-view

I am having multiple crashes on play store console, I have checked all images in the drawable folder and it seems to be fine to me as I suspect this can cause the issue. It is mostly crashing on samsung devices as per report. Please suggest what wrong is happening.
Also for background images I am using this size:
hdpi :480*800
xhdpi: 640*960
xxhdpi 1440*2560
xxxhdpi: 1440*2560

```
`at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw 
(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap (Canvas.java:1420)
at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw (BitmapDrawable.java:545)
at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw (ImageView.java:1286)
at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18318)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17296)
at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17291)
at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17291)
at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17291)
at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17291)
at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17291)
at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)
at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18321)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw (DecorView.java:919)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17296)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList 
(ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList 
(ThreadedRenderer.java:698)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw (ThreadedRenderer.java:806)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw (ViewRootImpl.java:3128)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw (ViewRootImpl.java:2924)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2516)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1515)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7091)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:927)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:702)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:638)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run 
(Choreographer.java:913)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)`.
```

Comment: Is it all version of os 4.x ?

Comment: It is mostly on android 7.0.

Comment: What extension are you using for your background images? And their dimension in MB?

Comment: Dimension I am using is  I am using this size: hdpi :480*800 xhdpi: 640*960 xxhdpi 1080*1920 xxxhdpi: 1440*2560 and size is in KB. Hope you mean this

Answer (score 0):

I think that your Exception starts from here:

```
protected void throwIfCannotDraw(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap.isRecycled()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap " + bitmap);
    }
    if (!bitmap.isPremultiplied() && bitmap.getConfig() == Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 &&
            bitmap.hasAlpha()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Canvas: trying to use a non-premultiplied bitmap "
                + bitmap);
    }
    throwIfHwBitmapInSwMode(bitmap);
}
```

So or you are trying to use a recycled bitmap or your bmp is not premultiplied or your hardware does'nt support bitmaps

```
private void throwIfHwBitmapInSwMode(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (!mAllowHwBitmapsInSwMode && !isHardwareAccelerated()
            && bitmap.getConfig() == Bitmap.Config.HARDWARE) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps");
    }
}
```

but i don't think!

SO now try to load images as follow to avoid errors and let me know:

```
mImageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, 100, 100));

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

For [reference](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap#read-bitmap).

Comment: the problem is I am getting this log on play store and I am setting background image at multiple places so I don't know where to write the above piece of code.

Comment: Simply write this code in all the places. This make your code faster and less-memory-consumer!

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing this issue from last 7 days and the solution is nothing but just need to check all imageview in XML where you specifically mentioned height and width and the drawable which you are assigning to that view is too large.